# как реализовать возможность перемещения элементов

Tags: javascript

```js
    addEventListener("click", function () {
        const labels = [...document.querySelectorAll('[name="emails"]:checked + label')];
        document.getElementById("emails").innerText = labels.map(function(label) {
            return label.innerText
        }).join(', ');
    });
```

```css
.content {
    background: #84a1e0;
    height: 500px;
    width: 1000px;
    margin: 40px auto;
}
.content > button{
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, 0);
    top: 50%;
}
.listName1 {
    background: #d6d6d6;
    height: 420px;
    width: 350px;
    margin-top: 80px;

}.listName2 {
     background: #d6d6d6;
     height: 420px;
     width: 350px;
     margin-top: 80px;
 }

.grid-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
    gap: 0px 0px;
}

.Content { grid-area: 1 / 1 / 3 / 6; }

.listName1 { grid-area: 1 / 2 / 3 / 3; }

.listName2 { grid-area: 1 / 4 / 3 / 5; }
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
    <div class="Content">
        <button>>></button>
        <button><<</button>
    </div>
    <div class="listName1">

        <input type="checkbox" name="emails" id="em1">
        <label for="em1">Rain@gmail.com</label><br>

        <input type="checkbox" name="emails" id="em2">
        <label for="em2">Train@gmail.com</label><br>

        <input type="checkbox" name="emails" id="em3">
        <label for="em3">Snow@gmail.com</label><br>

        <input type="checkbox" name="emails" id="em4">
        <label for="em4">White@gmail.com</label><br>

        <input type="checkbox" name="emails" id="em5">
        <label for="em5">Bleak@gmail.com</label><br>

        <input type="checkbox" name="emails" id="em6">
        <label for="em6">Green@gmail.com</label><br>

        <input type="checkbox" name="emails" id="em7">
        <label for="em7">Geek@gmail.com</label><br>

        <input type="checkbox" name="emails" id="em8">
        <label for="em8">Son@gmail.com</label><br>

        <input type="checkbox" name="emails" id="em9">
        <label for="em9">Bohdan@gmail.com</label><br>

        <input type="checkbox" name="emails" id="em10">
        <label for="em10">Ukraine@gmail.com</label><br>

    </div>
    <div class="listName2">
        <div id="emails"></div>

    </div>
</div>
```

как реализовать возможность перемещения элементов, что бы порядок сохрантлся. При выборм чекбокса, при нажатии кнопки ">>" они перемещаются вправо и назад так само

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а поточнее можете сказать, что именно нужно то? что двигается, куда двигается?

Comment: c блока listName1 в listName2.
Ну типо, можна выбрать елемент и кнопкой переместить в listName2 или назад
А перемещать вместе с чекбокс

Comment: Tekk, т.е. я ставлю чекбокс на элементе, нажимаю >> и он опускается вниз?

Comment: он перемещается в блок справа(listName2)

Comment: @Zhihar по сути, так как вы написали.чекбокс на элементе, нажимаю >> и он перемещается в блок справа(listName2) и назад при нажатии <<

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По предложенной картинке мне кажется возможно 2 варианта - правильный и извращённый, но легкий :)

**правильный:**

1. при создании списка каждому элементу поставить в соответствие некоторый атрибут `my-order`, в котором будет записан исходный порядок (не обязательно 1,2,3, можно и другие числа, главное чтобы отсортированными они образовывали нужный изначальный порядок)
2. `<label /><input />` лучше завернуть в `<div id = "..." class = "input-block" my-order="...">`
3. при нажатии на кнопку `>>` (или `<<`) проходим по массиву

   querySelectorall('.input-block')

копируем в `listName2` и удаляем из `listName1`

4. скопированные блоки сортируем по значениям из `my-order`

по идее это можно сделать в 2 этапа - сначала копируем блоки из `listName2` в массив, сортируем массив, удаляем все блоки из `listName2`, а потом формируем их из массива

**простой, но извращённый**

1. `<label /><input />` лучше завернуть в `<div id = "..." class = "input-block" my-order="...">`
2. продублировать чекбоксы (блоки `div`) как в блоке `listName1` так и в блоке `listName2`
3. если пользователь нажал >>, то проходим по `div` в `listName2` И делаем их там видимыми (выставляем `display: block;`), а в `listName1` делаем невидимыми (выставляем `display: none`)

Comment: атрибут my-order, это класс?

Comment: @Tekk, нет - просто свой атрибут в тег вставляете, чтоб не конфликтовать случайно с другими, реально существующими:

`<div my-order=1></div><div my-order=2></div>` и т.д.

Comment: @Zhihar для этого ведь и созданы стандартные дата-атрибуты `data-order="1"` чтобы не выдумывать разные названия)

Comment: @OPTIMUS PRIME, тогда супер, я, честно говоря, не знал

Comment: @Zhihar Как правильно копировать и вырезать елемент, что бы ставить
`document.getElementById("button1").addEventListener("click", function () {

    const values = document.querySelectorAll('.input-block')
    let checkBoxes = document.getElementsByName("countries");
    let idArray = [];
    for(let emails of checkBoxes){
        if(emails.checked === true){
            idArray.push(emails.id.toString());
        }
    }
    document.getElementById("listName2").innerText = idArray.join(", ");
});`

Comment: @Tekk можно использовать `document.createElement`, `insertBefore` и `.innerHtml` _ посмотрите примеры